# "Monitoring and Status" equivalent in Exchange 2010

Tags: monitoring, exchange-2003, exchange-2010

Exchange 2003 had some pretty basic monitoring built in. If a queue got stuck, it could send you an email notifying you of the problem. You could also monitor a few other aspects of the server. This was pretty handy for my organization--just about all of the monitoring we needed.

We've upgraded to Exchange 2010, and this functionality seems to have disappeared. Is there a hidden equivalent somewhere? The Google was unable to help me, nor was the manual/online documentation.

Eventually I would like to implement a more comprehensive monitoring system--I've been eying Nagios--but immediately it would be great to get the basics up and running again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a hidden equivalent
>   somewhere?

SCOM - System Center operations Manager. At the end MS decided that redundant functionality is of no real use to most of it's users and removed it. I suggest you start implementing a company wide monitoring approach, then Exchagne Servers fall naturally into proper monitoring.

Comment: We do have one solution--What's Up Gold. I'm not a big fan of its capabilities though, which is why I would like to try Nagios. What's Up Gold also doesn't do a great job of monitoring Exchange at a granular level.

It sucks that MS decided to remove basic functionality and require you to pay for it in a separate product.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you IP Monitor Monitoring software instead of Nagios, I have used both there is lots of issue with Nagios like Service down or reboot required etc., other hand with IP Monitor there is almost all feature available like Disk Usage Monitoring, Service State Monitoring, CPU Usage, etc.,

I would personally suggest look at IP monitor before purchasing any other monitoring software.

Comment: A proprietary monitoring solution is not really a good solution here. Thanks anyway.